# A proxy handler that can handle multiple proxies

Tags: networking, proxy, socks-proxy, http-proxy

for example, i have this local proxies handlers:

```
127.0.0.1:8888 (Fiddler)
127.0.0.1:1080 (ShadowSocks)
127.0.0.1:919 (Another ShadowSocks)
```

I want them to be used at the same time. is there any software that can connect to them at every new connection?

For example: I set up my browser's proxy to 127.0.0.1:12345 (The proxy that can connect to multiple other proxies).

Then i tried to browse http://website.com
The request headers will be sent to 127.0.0.1:8888 (Fiddler).

Next when the response body is received, let's assume that there's a

```
<img src="dog.jpeg"><script src="script.js">
```

In the response body and the script is not cached. Now my browser will send another request to the proxy that can handle multiple proxies to get the http://website.com/script.js

The proxy that can handle multiple proxies will now connect to 127.0.0.1:1080 (ShadowSocks) to get the script.js and also connect to 127.0.0.1:919 (Another ShadowSocks) to get the image.

I think you already get my point right? Is there any software that can do this? Or is there anyway to accomplish this thing in python using sockets and urllib?

Comment: Woah is 3/4 of the population in the world died already?

Comment: [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) should be able to do this, you can use scripts to set how and where to connect upstream via for each request. You'd just need a way to round-robin them, which should be possible using global counters. Disclaimer I work for Qbik who are the author of WinGate.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is visited 17 times by good people, I've found an answer for my question. Thanks for @Adrien for trying to help me but This can be done easily by using PAC script!

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    var q = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    switch(q) {
        case 1 : 
        return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:1080";
        break;
        case 2 :
        return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:1090";
        break;
        case 0 :
        return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:1070";
        break;
        default :
        return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:1080";
        break;
    }
}
```

If you see q is generating random number from 0 to 2 then making a proxy depending on the number generated.

Next is by configuring my browser Auto configuration [Click here for PAC Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhc25.png)

Wolah! Piece of cake!